# Shopify Admin API:Cannot upload asset to Layout folder - 422 error

Tags: rest, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api, http-status-code-422

I'm using the the admin API to make a restful PUT request to upload some file to theme folders.

I can successfully upload files to any folder other that the 'Layout' folder, which gives a 422 error. Uploading to assets, templates sections etc works perfectly.

I'm using the below PUT request and payload.

```
PUT /admin/api/2020-04/themes/{themeID}/assets.json


{
"asset": {
"key": "layout/themes-test.liquid",
"value": "The HTML FOR THEME.LIQUID"
}
}
```

Does the Layout folder require some special permissions for upload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Shopify expects the following to be present within the head and body tags respectively:

{{content_for_header}} and {{content_for_layout}}

Injecting the following satisfies the above requirement and works!

```
{
"asset": {
"key": `layout/theme-test.liquid`,
"value": `<head>{{content_for_header}}</head><body>{{content_for_layout}}</body>`
}
}
```